# Bdd Cucumber issues

Tags: scala, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-junit

I have newly started working on BDD Cucumber. I am using scala for writing test cases. I am trying to use Scenario Outline and passing parameters in step definitions. My code is as follows.

```
Scenario Outline:  Data is parsed and persisted
    Given Portal is running
    When A data of <type> is received
    Then The data of <type> with <Id> should be parsed and persisted

  

      Examples:
        | type        | Id  |
        | Personal    | 1   |
        |Professional | 2   |
```

Now in my when condition I am trying to  get these parameters as follows

```
When("""^A data of \"([^\"]*)\" is received$""") {
(type: String) => 
//My code
}
```

Now on running my code I am getting following error everytime.

```
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step "A data of Personal is received" is undefined. You can implement it using the snippet(s) below:

When("""A data of Personal is received""") { () =>
  // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  throw new io.cucumber.scala.PendingException()
}
```

Though I have my code in when. Also If I don't use Scenario  Outline then it works fine but I want to use Scenario Outline for my code.

2. I am using tags in my feature file to run my test cases. When I run my test cases with command sbt test @tag1, test cases executes fine but when all test cases are finished running on cmd I am getting following error:

   ```
    [error] Expected ';'

    [error] @tag1
   ```

I tried putting ";" after  tag but still getting same error
What is this issue and how I can resolve it?

3. I have 4-5 feature files in my application. That means 4-5 tags. As of now the test case which I want to run I give path of feature file and "glue" it with step  deinition in my Runner Class. How I can provide all the tags in my Runner class so that my application runs all the  test cases one by one when started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the double quotes around `<type>`:

```
When A data of "<type>" is received
```

Comment: Hi It worked after using "<type>"could you please help on other two question as well?

Comment: @zaib333: Please post separate questions for those.

Answer (score 0):

Just some general advice.

When cuking keep things as simple as possible, focus on clarity and simplicity, do not worry about repetition.

Your task would be much simpler if you wrote 2 simple scenarios

```
Scenario: Personal data
  Given Portal is running
  When personal data is received
  Then personal data should be persisted

Scenario: Professional data
  ...
```

Secondly don't use tags to run your features, you don't need tags yet.

You can cuke much more effectively if you avoid scenario outlines, regex's, tags, transforms etc. etc.. The main power in Cucumber is using natural language to express yourself clearly. Focus on that and keep it simple ...